# data is not saving in mongodb compass .inside thunder client body i have passed a json according to model schema . but data is not saving in mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, thunderclient

**data is not saving in mongodb compass . i have used node js to connect to mongodb . a router is also there . model schema is also present .inside thunder client body i have passed a json according to model schema . app listen is working fine and connection to mongodb is also successful . but i could not see those passed data in my mongodb.literally i have tried everything but could not get any solution how to save my data ?**

**db.js (mongo server)**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const mongoURI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/"
const connectToMongo = ()=>{
    mongoose.connect(mongoURI, { useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology:true },()=>{
        console.log("Connected to Mongo Successfully");
    })
}

module.exports = connectToMongo;
```

**index.js (express and mongo server)**

```
const connectToMongo = require('./db');  //here we import db.js from the above
const express = require('express');

  

connectToMongo();
const app = express();
const port = 3000;


app.use(express.json());

// Available Routes
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/auth')) //one route ./api/auth is the route


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`iNotebook backend listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

**auth router**

```
const express = require("express")
const User = require("../models/User") //User schema described below.
const router = express.Router()

router.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body)
    const user=User(req.body)
    user.save()
    res.send(req.body)
})
module.exports = router
```

**User schema inside model folder**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;
 
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
  });
  const User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
  module.exports = User;
```

**picture of thunder client**

**here you can see https://localhost:300/api/auth is the router . in body i have given name ,email,password and response i am getting right . and also it is showing connected to mongo successfully.**

[image: here you can see https://localhost:300/api/auth is the router . in body i have given name ,email,password and response i am getting right . and also it is showing connected to mongo successfully.]
**picture of mongodb compass.**

**where my passed body data that is name,email,password is saving in mongodb compass**
[image: where my passed body data that is name,email,password is saving in mongodb compass]

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `db.js`. Replace `localhost:27017` with `127.0.0.1:27017`.

```
const mongoURI = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/';
```